# How to add dependencies to buildscript dynamically?

Tags: android, gradle, build-script

I want to add my gradle plugin to root project's buildscript's dependencies. For example, my andorid project's root's `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        // I want add a new classpath here
    }
}
```

I do it at app project's `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
getRootProject().getBuildscript().getDependencies().add("classpath", "com.sensorsdata.analytics.android:android-gradle-plugin2:3.3.3")
```

when i sync Gradle, it comes follow error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':classpath' after it has been resolved.
```

Now how could i modify buildscript's dependencies dynamically? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not possible from within the system, because any code you could execute from the buildscript will only run after the buildscript's dependencies have been evaluated (makes sense, after a while). So you'd have to run a shell script or something before invoking Gradle.

Comment: But maybe you can just always add that plugin, and disable its tasks when you don't need them? That would be possible.